# Binding With jQuery, wrong order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, bind

I have this script that loads in content, and should then bind the delete link to remove the content.

However I'm finding that it isnt binding with the delete link, even then I put the code in a function that should rebind.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    function loadImages() {
        $.get('/management/image/get/site_id/1/area/News', function(data) {
            $("#existing-images").html(data);
        });

        $(".deleteImage").click(function() {
            id = $(this).attr('id'); id = id.split('_');
            alert(id);
            /*$.post(second_url+'id/'+id, '', function(theResponse) {
                $("#image_"+id+"").remove();
            });*/
        });
    }


    $("#fileInput").uploadify({
        'uploader'       : '/library/jquery/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script'         : '/gallery/image/area/site_id/<?php echo $site->id; ?>/area/<?php echo $this->area; ?>',
        'cancelImg'      : '/library/jquery/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'folder'         : '/images/Image/',
        'multi'          : true,
        'onAllComplete'  : function(e, queueId, file, response, data) {
            $('#fileInput').uploadifyClearQueue();
            loadImages();
        },
    });


    loadImages();


});
```

Comment: Check the spelling/capitalisation of your 'deleteImage' id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [$.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function to dynamically bind delete links instead of doing it every time you make an request.

try something like:

```
//..init code
$(".deleteImage").live('click',function() {
        id = $(this).attr('id'); id = id.split('_');
        alert(id);
});

function loadImages() {
    $.get('/management/image/get/site_id/1/area/News', function(data) {
            $("#existing-images").html(data);
    });
}

//more code here...
```

Comment: I like this solution the most, though its probably frowned upon?

Comment: What do you mean by "frowned upon"?

Answer (score 1):

you are binding the delete link before ajax request complete.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the asynchronous nature of the ajax call.

The code you have writen tries to bind the click event to a button that has not yet been injected into the DOM

Try changing your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    function loadImages() {
        $.get('/management/image/get/site_id/1/area/News', function(data) {
            $("#existing-images").html(data);

            $(".deleteImage").click(function() {
                id = $(this).attr('id'); id = id.split('_');
                alert(id);
                /*$.post(second_url+'id/'+id, '', function(theResponse) {
                    $("#image_"+id+"").remove();
                });*/
            });
        });


    }



    $("#fileInput").uploadify({
        'uploader'       : '/library/jquery/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script'         : '/gallery/image/area/site_id/<?php echo $site->id; ?>/area/<?php echo $this->area; ?>',
        'cancelImg'      : '/library/jquery/uploadify/cancel.png',
        'folder'         : '/images/Image/',
        'multi'          : true,
        'onAllComplete'  : function(e, queueId, file, response, data) {
            $('#fileInput').uploadifyClearQueue();
            loadImages();
        },
    });


    loadImages();
});
```

Moving the binding into the success callback of the `$.get` call makes sure that the new html has been injected before the binding occurs.

Alternativly try looking into using [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of binding to the element, that way you don't need to rebind all the time